# Why php if else is not working with JSON data

Tags: php, json

I am fetching information from my database as JSON array.The problem is i am unable to use this data to compare using if else or assign to a PHP variable.

query:

```
$query="select * from dmo";

$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

$arr = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[] = $row;  
    }
}
# JSON-encode the response
$json_response = json_encode($arr);

// # Return the response
echo $json_response;
```

Data:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
                    <td>{{data.tran_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.tran_type}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.sender}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.amount}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.fee}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.date}}</td>
                    <td>
                    <?php $s="{{data.status}}"; if ($s == "0")
                    echo"Pending"; 
                    else if ($s == "1") echo"Completed"; 
                    ?>
                    </td>


                </tr>
```

Comment: For example {{data.amount}} will look like 20 or something that is stored in my DB!

Comment: Are you mixing php with javascript??

Comment: Normal if else are also not working!And why the down vote ??

Comment: What do you mean by normal? `ng-if`?

Comment: ({{data.status}}==1) ? "Too young":"Old enough";

Comment: That's not how angular templates work. You can try this `{{ data.status == 1 ? "Too young" : "Old enough" }}`

Comment: Do some research on what PHP actually is and what it does, before you use it! Downvote because this code is nonsensical and you obviously haven't taken the time to discover what PHP and JavaScript actually do. Or run a "View Source" operation! And before you accuse me of downvoting "because I don't know the answer", see below.

Comment: (Hi user2252617, I've removed the commentary about voting from the question, as it is not relevant to the question itself. If you want to comment about votes it is best to do that in comments.)

Comment: Are you using Angular here as well? If so, it's worth bearing in mind that Angular does things in the browser, via JavaScript, but PHP does them in the server. So, your PHP `if` statement has already been processed by the time the page is first rendered, and that bit won't change. My guess is you need to find an Angular directive for what you want to do. If you need dynamic information from the server, it supports AJAX operations too.

Comment: Thanks to both lukasgeiter  and  halfer for their polite and comments.Halfer has explained the matter in the way as i expect as a beginner.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit,i have already worked with java script and JSON data but for the 1st time working with angular js,so some mistake may happen as a beginner(as i always see that java script remains inside the script tag).But the way you commenting is looking very aggressive to me .My mistake doesn't make any sense to u because u are considering this 4m your side that means 4m an experts view!Don't you think it was better to explain  the mistake politely as others doing without the down vote?Or you  think down vote is the only  way to punish the beginners who does silly mistakes?

Comment: @user2252617 Downvotes are not "punishment"; they reflect my opinion on the quality of the question and its usefulness for others. This one is just a misunderstanding due to lack of research.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us anything about how your templating engine works or which one it is, but it seems clear enough from your problem that it's not preprocessed PHP. You can't just mix technologies like that and expect it to work.

Read up about how PHP is invoked, what its result is, how that result is transferred to a browser and how that browser interprets what it's received; you'll see that what you wrote doesn't make any sense.

More than likely, the templating engine you're using will have its own conditional syntax. For example, in AngularJS you would write:

```
{{data.status == 1 ? "Too young" : "Old enough"}}
```

Have a good read through the documentation for the technologies that you use.